# How to access intranet web services over internet

Tags: asp.net, web-services, intranet

I have a web application developed in visual studio 2015 in c#. This web application is back-end and which runs only in intranet.

We have mobile app as front-end which access some web services written in the back-end app. This front-end mobile app is available on internet.

Mobile users login to server using one of the web services. Whatever data / server accessed by mobile users, are through web services.

So are these web services can be accessible through front-end app without doing anything?

Or how can we make available web services to access through front-end mobile app over internet.

What should we do?

---

So far our both back-end and front-end both were on intranet or both were on internet, so was not a problem. Now it's mix of intranet and internet (back-end with web services - intranet, front-end which access web services - internet) , so not sure what we need to change so web services will be accessible over internet.

Comment: if your mobile app needs to access your web services, then your web services will need to be internet-facing (either directly, probably not a good idea) or via some sort of gateway. Exactly how you do it depends on a lot of factors - the topology of your existing network, your security apparatus, any applicable standards and governance, quality of your services, expected volumes, and more. A good technical or applications architect will be able to help you with this kind of thing. There are also consultancies out there which claim to provide secure wrappers for your internal APIs etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Have to do more research.